# Will I get OTA updates if I reflash official rom after modifying a Samsung device?

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a S5 duos on custom rom, Now if I reflaah the official firmware from samfirmware and flash it and then select **Check for updates** will I be able to receive updates of will it show 'Your device have been modified'?

P.s knox counter is now on 0×1 (4)

Comment: Is your stock ROM rooted?

Comment: I rooted my stock ROM then flashed TWRP recovery and then flashed custom ROM

Comment: But I have downloaded the official stock rom will i be able to update if i flash it?

Comment: You should be able to get updates, but just in case make a full backup in TWRP so you can go back.

Comment: I flashed CM12 to my Moto G2, then flashed Stock ROM (5.0.2), haven't got the OTA update. What do I do?